# How to make a div visible and hidden on selecting different radio button in mvc using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is my view

```html
if (ViewBag.delivery != "1")
{
    <div id="shipdetail">
        <label>Shipping Details</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <p>Shipping Address</p>
            @Html.TextBox("ship_address", null, new { @class = "form-control valid", @data_val = "true", @data_val_required = "Shipping Address" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#shipdetail").hide();

    $("input[name='DiscountedPrice']").change(function () {
        $("#shipdetail").toggle();
    });
});
```

I want to hide this part when I click the first radio button and show the part when I click the second radio button. Here is my radio button part. It is inside an else part of a condition.

```html
else 
{
    <div class="form-inline">
        <label>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.DiscountedPrice, "Pick from store", new { @class = "form-control valid", @data_val = "true", @data_val_required = "Delivery Type" })
        </label>
        <label>I can pick it from the store</label><br />

        <label>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.DiscountedPrice, "Need door delivery", new { @class = "form-control valid", @data_val = "true", @data_val_required = "Delivery Type" })
        </label>
        <label>I would like to get it on my door</label><br />
    </div>
}
```

What is the error here? I cant do the hide/show here.?

Comment: What is the element with `id="billdetail"`? (or should that be `$("#shipdetail").toggle();`?

Comment: yes.. it is shipdetail.still not working

Comment: I need to show the part when I clicked "I would like to get it on my door" and need to hide when i clicked "I would like to get it on my door"

Comment: I assume you last comment is not quite right - you repeated the same text twice :). Clicking on the `label` element that contains the text wont do anything (you need to add the text to the label above it and delete the second one)

Comment: Not really clear from your question, but best guess is that you want it to be as per [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ujhkL22/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on view source and see the HTML,
It looks like your shipdetail is not rendered  when the radio button is rendered 
(if delivery, than render shipdetails, if not, render radiobuttons, MVC if and else are in Server side)
So you cannot change shipdetails appearance in client side, because it doesn't exists, instead of  if and else section, you should hide or show your div in css

```
 <div id="shipdetail" style='display:@ViewBag.Delivery!='1'?"none":"inline"'>
    <label>Shipping Details</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <p>Shipping Address</p>
        @Html.TextBox("ship_address", null, new { @class = "form-control                valid", @data_val = "true", @data_val_required = "Shipping Address" })
    </div>
</div>
```

--No if, No else

```
       <div class="form-inline">
    <label>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.DiscountedPrice, "Pick from store", new { @class = "form-control valid", @data_val = "true", @data_val_required = "Delivery Type" })
    </label>
    <label>I can pick it from the store</label><br />

    <label>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.DiscountedPrice, "Need door delivery", new { @class = "form-control valid", @data_val = "true", @data_val_required = "Delivery Type" })
    </label>
    <label>I would like to get it on my door</label><br />
</div>
```